# Typo3: Extern links extra class. Where is stored?

Tags: backend, typo3, rte

I made an extension which uses the header_link field to set up links. Problem is that with external links I want the `<a>` tag with an extra class, which is ok since there is a field for that in the backend. Problem is, I dont know where this value is stored. Anyone can help me, please?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if I understood your question right, but I gave my best to help you out here.

Comment: Just to get updated: Is this answer working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re-reading your question, I think the answer is simpler then I initially thought.
Standard link fields are a string stored to the database like that:

```
www.linktarget.com - - - customlinkclass
```

Which pretty much explains itself. You can access the values seperately with `t3lib_div::trimExplode()` in your extensions php code, then create the link with `tslib_cObj::typoLink`

However, I don't know exactly what you mean with `header_link` field.